# MSI G41M P33 Combo motherboard beeps

Tags: motherboard, ddr3

I thought of upgrading my old desktop and hence bought **MSI G41M P33 COMBO** mobo and **Transcend 4GB DDR3 RAM (JM1333KLN-4G)** ram. However when I have installed (mobo+ DDR3 ram) the mobo beeps 3 times. So I put in the old DDR2 ram and it worked.

I have updated the bios and have tried the DDR3 ram again. Although the beep sound stopped the PC keeps restarting. DDR3 ram is not working.

I want to use the new DDR3 ram, so could any one suggest how will that work.

**MSI motherboard description**
[image]

**DDR3 Ram details**
[image]

Mobo image
[image]

Comment: Are they the same slots or different slots? Is there some bios setting for this? I didn't realise that boards that handle two different types of ram existed 0_0

Comment: Different slots. I have added the mobo image.

Comment: Ahh, let me know on chat if you don't have an answer. Also, does the ram work in *another* system?

Comment: Yes, both my Ram old DDR2 and new DDR3 are working but the DDR3 is not working for this mobo.

Comment: https://forum-en.msi.com/index.php?topic=176120.0 indicates updating your bios might help *but* these boards are picky over what sort of ram they take

Comment: I have updated the bios, still DDR3 is not working.

Comment: Back when this board was made, the layout of the chips themselves on the ddr3 ram module were one important aspect of compatability with the chipset. Boards like this also did not have a huge compatability list, but at least that list and the memory information in the manuel could be used to try and find ram modules that might work.  You could also have better luck with 2gig modules. if your only running a 32bit system the 4 gig would be enough. As you already know you cannot run both types ddr2 and ddr3 at the same time, on most boards of this type.

Answer (score 1):

You need to overclock your motherboard configuration by going into bios menu then enter cell menu and see where are dram settings set mhz to 1333 and boOom ram will work.